# RDBMS timestamp to Hive timestamp timezone mismatch

Tags: database, date, hadoop, timezone, hive

If I query an RDBMS to get a timestamp I receive: `2015-03-30 00:00:00`
After I export it to a Hive table as a bigint column I get `1427673600000` (`cast(ts as timestamp) gives 2015-03-30 02:00:00`) . I.e the current local timezone (with daylight savings) has been applied to the timestamp.

If I want to be consistent of what we have in the DB, how to store the exported timestamps in Hive? Do I need to always store timestamps as UTC format in Hive so in this case I need to substract 2 hours from what I got
and then I have to apply the current timezone during querying (using `from_utc_timestamp`) ? 
How can I take into consideration daylight savings (GMT+1 and GMT+2) ?

What is the best practice?

Comment: Past timestamps should always be stored as UTC.  The exception is that if you also need *also* need to correlate local times, then you store the local time in a separate field, or use a `datetimeoffset` when the platform supports it.  (Future times are an entirely different matter.)   This is in the best practices, linked as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have any Hive related add-on / best practices?

Comment: Re-opening to add details for Hive. (Originally marked as dup of [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2532962/634824))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive stores timestamps in milliseconds since the Unix epoch.  The [Hive docs on timestamps](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-Timestamps) are actually wrong that it is "timezoneless", as the Unix Epoch is *by definition* in UTC.

The timestamp you gave (`1427673600000`) does indeed correspond to `2015-03-30 00:00:00 UTC`.  If this is the instant in time that you intended to store, then you are doing it correctly.  If actually you were intending to just store a calendar date (referring to the *whole* date, rather than midnight UTC on that date), then you should probably use the [`DATE`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-dateDates) type instead, storing just `2015-03-30`.

You asked why `cast(ts as timestamp)` gives `2015-03-30 02:00:00`.  What's probably happening here, is that the time is being *exported* with the original timestamp, but when you *receive* it, it is getting loaded into a type that shows you the local time equivalent.

For example, this can happen with `java.util.Date`.  You should be able to take this value and interpret it differently, either with `java.util.Calendar`, or Joda-Time, or the new Java 8 `java.time` classes.  If you're not using Java, then a similar approach would likely still apply.  The point is, you're probably using *Hive* correctly, but the local time zone is being introduced as you view the results.

> Do I need to always store timestamps as UTC format in Hive ...

Yes, that's the best practice, and that's what you're doing already.

> ... so in this case I need to subtract 2 hours from what I got ...

No, you should never manually add or subtract time from the timestamp.  Doing so will put you at an entirely different point in time.

> ... and then I have to apply the current timezone during querying (using `from_utc_timestamp`) ?

I'm not completely familiar with Hive. Looking at [the docs for `from_utc_timestamp`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions), it would appear this expects the input to already be in a timestamp, but they show an example using a string.  Perhaps it will take an integer also, but then you would just pass `UTC` as the time zone, essentially doing nothing in the value conversion.  It's likely that you would still have the same problem, especially if the problem is on the receiving end.  IMHO, I don't think you should have to use this.

Comment: If you can provide any more details about how you are receiving the value being exported, I may be able to provide more information.